# Apache isis helloworld archtype build failure

Tags: maven, maven-3, isis

I am getting started with Apache isis (I have Windows 10) and following their tutorial (https://isis.apache.org/guides/ugfun/ugfun.html#_ugfun_getting-started_helloworld-archetype)

I installed Java and Maven, added them to the path and then I created a folder inside which when I run command `mvn -v` I see folling output:

```
E:\Apache isis\test_project>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T20:49:05+01:00)
Maven home: D:\Development softwares\apache-maven-3.5.3-bin\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..
Java version: 9.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.4
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

When I run the command specified in their docs to generate app:

```
mvn archetype:generate  \
    -D archetypeGroupId=org.apache.isis.archetype \
    -D archetypeArtifactId=helloworld-archetype \
    -D archetypeVersion=1.16.2 \
    -D groupId=com.mycompany \
    -D artifactId=myapp \
    -D version=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
    -B
```

I get following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Nitish> cd .\Desktop\
PS C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop> mvn archetype:generate  \
>>     -D archetypeGroupId=org.apache.isis.archetype \
>>     -D archetypeArtifactId=simpleapp-archetype \
>>     -D archetypeVersion=1.16.2 \
>>     -D groupId=com.mycompany \
>>     -D artifactId=myapp \
>>     -D version=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
>>     -B
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.114 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-20T15:42:22+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
-D : The term '-D' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:5
+     -D archetypeGroupId=org.apache.isis.archetype \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-D:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-D : The term '-D' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:5
+     -D archetypeArtifactId=simpleapp-archetype \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-D:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-D : The term '-D' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:4 char:5
+     -D archetypeVersion=1.16.2 \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-D:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-D : The term '-D' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:5 char:5
+     -D groupId=com.mycompany \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-D:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-D : The term '-D' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:6 char:5
+     -D artifactId=myapp \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-D:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-D : The term '-D' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:7 char:5
+     -D version=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-D:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-B : The term '-B' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:8 char:5
+     -B
+     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-B:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Am I missing out something?

Answer (score 1):

As I was using Powershell I had to use the command :

```
mvn archetype:generate  "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.isis.archetype" "-DarchetypeArtif
actId=helloworld-archetype" "-DarchetypeVersion=1.16.2" "-DgroupId=com.mycompany" "-DartifactId=myapp" "-Dversion=1.0-SN
APSHOT" "-B"
```

Comment: With Powershell the continuation character is a backtick ` rather than a backslash \

Answer (score 0):

For Unix, it should as below.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.beam \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=beam-sdks-java-maven-archetypes-examples \
  -DarchetypeVersion=2.14.0 \
  -DgroupId=org.example \
  -DartifactId=word-count-beam \
  -Dversion="0.1" \
  -Dpackage=org.apache.beam.examples \
  -DinteractiveMode=false
```

If you want to use it in powershell replace backslash \ with backtick `